# how to extract a substring in a text file, when the substring is between two parentheses?

Tags: string, matlab

I have a text file that contains sections as shown below

```
V1('ww', '6deg')
V2('bb', '15meter') 
V3('cc','25yards')
.
.
V4('dd', '72cm')
```

these sections are randomly distributed inside the text file.
Using MATLAB, I need to find all the occurrences of VariableProp(VarName,  VarValue) in the file, and change the VarValue.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `textscan`. (You could also probably do it with `regexp`). Here's a `textscan` approach:

```
str = "V4('dd', '72cm')"; % a line from the file
% Call textscan on a single line of text
x = textscan(str, "%[^(](%[^']%[^'])", ...
      MultipleDelimsAsOne=true, Delimiter=[","," ", "'"]);
% x is a 3-element cell array. If we got a match, each element in the
% outer cell is a scalar. Use vertcat to unwrap a layer of cell-ness:
x = vertcat(x{:});
% If we're left with 3 elements, it was a match
isMatch = numel(x) == 3;
```

Comment: Thank you. what if I have many different sets of str spread out inside a  large text file? How do I then find the sets?

Comment: You can use `txt = fileread(...)` to get the whole file contents as text. Then `lines = strsplit(txt, newline)` to divide into individual lines. Loop over `lines` checking to see if each matches.

Comment: Actually scratch that last suggestion. Just use `readlines` https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readlines.html to read the lines of text directly. Loop over the lines and check for matches using that `textscan` approach. (Most approaches are a bit awkward if you have a mix of matching and non-matching lines I think, but maybe there are other ways)